# Auto re-deploy Docker container?

Tags: docker, jelastic

I understand how to add a container image in Jelastic and also how to re-deploy, but I'm trying to have a CI/CD setup with Jelastic and I don't see a way to automate the re-deploying of a container image when a new image is updated in my container registry. Is there a way to do this in Jelastic?

Answer (score 1):

1. Issue a [personal access token](https://docs.jelastic.com/personal-access-tokens) only for one API method - [RedeployContainers](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Control-method-RedeployContainers)
2. Use rest API in your hooks

   > https://cs.{platformDomain}/1.0/environment/control/rest/redeploycontainers?token=${token}&tag=${tag}&envName=${envName}&nodeGroup=${nodeGroup}

There is a list of [predefined nodeGroups](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/selecting-containers/#predefined-nodegroup-values)